# Who is the young man mentioned in Mark 14:51?

Tags: new-testament

In [Mark 14:51-52](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%2014:51-52&version=NCV), there is this reference to a man:

> **51** A young man, wearing only a linen cloth, was following Jesus, and the people also grabbed him. **52** But the cloth he was wearing came off, and he ran away naked.

Who is this guy? Why is he mentioned? Does he have anything to do with the current situation?

Comment: That is commonly accepted to be [Mark himself](http://www.biblestudytools.com/commentaries/robertsons-word-pictures/mark/mark-14-51.html).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is one of only a very few incidents in the Gospel of Mark that does not appear anywhere else in the other three Gospels.  Some commentators have speculated, based on that, that the young man *was* Mark, referring to himself in the third person much as John did.  But that's just speculation; as far as I know there are no other passages that refer to our unfortunate anonymous disciple.

Comment: +1 Yup.  And [here's a commentary that supports this](http://www.biblestudytools.com/commentaries/robertsons-word-pictures/mark/mark-14-51.html).

Comment: Also supported by [this commentary](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/mark/14-51.htm).